# Discord Py How to check if it's the same string format but different variables from a list?

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm pretty new to python, I'm sorry if this question's bad, but I honestly don't know how to look or describe this.

I've been trying to make a bot respond to a certain phrase that has a format, but I'd like it to also respond to other words that I've put into a list when used in the format.

Here's what I've tried:

```
keywords = {
     "youre": ['ure', 'your'],
     "nice": ["good", "cool"]
}

if self.client.user.mentioned_in(message):
  mention = self.client.user.mention[:2] + '!' + self.client.user.mention[2:]
  replied = False

  for x in range(len(keywords["youre"]) + len(keywords["nice"])):
    if replied: return

    y = max(min(x, len(keywords["youre"]) - 1), 0)
    z = max(min(x, len(keywords["nice"]) - 1), 0)

    youre = keywords["youre"][y]
    nice = keywords["nice"][z]
    
    if (compare(msg, '{} {}'.format(youre, nice))):
      await message.reply(f'{random.choice(replies).format(name=getName(message))}')
      replied = True

      break
```

It works just fine, but there are only certain combinations that work if I increase the size of the list. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make a list of aliases, these examples do that:

```py
#If you need to keep it in different lists:
keywords = {
     "youre": ['ure', 'your', 'yar'],
     "nice": ["good", "cool", "pleasant"]
}

for x in range(len(keywords["youre"])):
    print(f'{(keywords["youre"])[x]} {(keywords["nice"])[x]}')

#Just to separate the outputs:
print("---------------")

#And if you don't care about the amount of lists:
aliases = ["ure good", "your cool", "yar pleasant"]
for x in aliases:
    print(x)

#Just to separate the outputs:
print("---------------")

#And if you need all the possible combinations:
keywords = {
     "youre": ['ure', 'your', 'yar', 'yer', 'u are'], #The lists have different lenghts, and one of the items has a space in it, yet it still works
     "nice": ["good", "cool", "pleasant"]
}

for x in keywords["youre"]:
    for y in keywords["nice"]:
        print(f"{x} {y}")
```

Output:

```
ure good
your cool
yar pleasant
---------------
ure good
your cool
yar pleasant
---------------
ure good
ure cool
ure pleasant
your good
your cool
your pleasant
yar good
yar cool
yar pleasant
yer good
yer cool
yer pleasant
u are good
u are cool
u are pleasant
```

Comment: oh, I must have not described it correctly, what my objective is making an "alias" for the "you're nice" phrase, like for example: when I type in "ure cool" the bot would detect it and execute the same code as if I was typing in "you're nice", I'm sorry if this is a bit confusing. I thought of using a for loop to iterate through the list and check them one by one if they are included but I ran into a problem when I have to use another list

Comment: @Ced, if you just want to make a list of aliases, then you can just make 1 list. Right? i thought you needed two to combine them and make all the combinations be aliases. I've updated the answer to match what you've told me in the comment.

Comment: oh, thanks! quick question tho, what should I do if I also want the other possible combinations? like say: "your good"? Also, if they don't have the same length, would clamping the index fix this problem?

Comment: @Ced Done! as you can see, if the lists don't have the same length, the simple system for getting all combinations still works, since it just iterates through everything.